# Match does not occur against value in defaultdict

Tags: defaultdict

```
for v in temp_var_dict['PSE2']:

                           #print(v)
                           match = str(match)
                           match = match.strip("[]")
                           match = match.strip("''")
                           print(f'** match={match}    v={v}    **')
                           result = [index for index, value in enumerate(v) if match in value]
```

I would expect to see  a match when comparing the results below. in my view match=1/2 and v=1/2/CPU0 should be a match and set 'result'=0. It is not happening though. Please kindly advise on proper syntax.

** match=1/2    v=0/7/CPU0    **

** match=1/2    v=1/0/CPU0    **

** match=1/2    v=1/2/CPU0    **
defaultdict(, {'PSE1': ['0/0/CPU0', '1/3/CPU0'], 'PSE2': ['0/7/CPU0', '1/0/CPU0', '1/2/CPU0'], 'IF_PSE1': [['TenGigE1/2/0/25.201', 'PSE2=NO', 25, 'TenGigE1/2', 'REPLICATION=NO'], ['TenGigE1/2/0/25.201', 'PSE2=NO', 25, 'TenGigE1/2', 'REPLICATION=NO'], ['TenGigE1/2/0/25.201', 'PSE2=NO', 25, 'TenGigE1/2', 'REPLICATION=NO']]})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, not completely sure, what you are looking for is the starting index of the substring if there is a match. For example if v = '1/2/CPU0' and match = '1/2'
there is a match and substring '1/2' starts at index '0' so result=0

Not sure what is wrong in your logic but str.find(substring) is your friend in this case. It will return -1 if no match is found and the starting index of the substring if a match is found.

See a modified 'working' version of your code below:

```
temp_var_dict = {'PSE1': ['0/0/CPU0', '1/3/CPU0'], 'PSE2': ['0/7/CPU0', '1/0/CPU0', '1/2/CPU0'], 'IF_PSE1': [['TenGigE1/2/0/25.201', 'PSE2=NO', 25, 'TenGigE1/2', 'REPLICATION=NO'], ['TenGigE1/2/0/25.201', 'PSE2=NO', 25, 'TenGigE1/2', 'REPLICATION=NO'], ['TenGigE1/2/0/25.201', 'PSE2=NO', 25, 'TenGigE1/2', 'REPLICATION=NO']]}

match = "1/2"

for v in temp_var_dict['PSE2']:
    match = str(match)
    match = match.strip("[]")
    match = match.strip("''")

    result = v.find(match)

    print "match={%s}    v={%s}  result={%s}" % (match,v,str(result))
```